# Visual Basic: How concatenate all string values from a multiline textbox with an specific delimiter

Tags: vb.net, textbox, delimiter, multiline

I need your help to fix my VB code.

I need to concatenate all the lines from the clipboard with this delimeter **","**

> only BETWEEN the lines and not at the beginning and the end

Then paste it into a multiline textbox and to the clipboard too.

I did everything but i got a problem with the concatenation:

Example:

the user will copy this text with Ctrl+C from a notepad:

12345

12345

12345

I can get this concatenation with my code:

','12345

12345

12345','

But I need the code to do this:

12345','12345','12345

Here is my VB code:

```
'This part gets the clipboard content with the delimiter (',') 

If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsText Then

   TextBox4.Text = "','" & My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText & "','"

End If
```

how would you change the code to get the delimiter only in between of each line  and not in the whole block as i did?

Thanks a lot!!!

Edited Answer:

I got a different approach (testing the delimiter copy from textbox to textbox)

```
For Each s As String In Me.TextBox4.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
            TextBox3.Text += s & "','"
Next
```

I almost got it, i got this now:

```
12345','
12345','
12345','
```

but i need this:

```
12345','
12345','
12345
```

any last idea to fix it?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
Dim initial As String 'Set String with line breaks here.
Dim final As String = String.Join("','", initial.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None))
```

or, even more simply, this:

```
Dim initial As String 'Set String with line breaks here.
Dim final As String = initial.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "','")
```

Answer (score 1):

As my first real app in VB I think is not the most suitable solution, but at least it works!

```
For Each s As String In Me.TextBox4.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
            TextBox3.Text += s & "','"
        Next

        Dim t As String
        t = TextBox3.Text

        TextBox3.Text = (t.Substring(0, t.Length - 3))
```

Ouput:

```
12345','12345','12345
```

Thanks everyone, im really happy!